# jquery delete a row of table (<tr>) through clicking a label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I developed a table and in each row there is 1 column and there are one check box and 2 labels in each row.

```js
$('input[type="label"]').click(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      $(this).parent("tr:first").remove()
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>To Do List</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" /><label>Task 1</label><label class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" /><label>Task 2</label><label class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" /><label>Task 3</label><label class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" id="3"></label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

when i click on delete label then the entire row should be deleted. and the row below it should automatically come one place above.

what corrections should be done in the jquery?

Comment: `input[type="label"]` ? is that correct?

Comment: and the parent is not a tr....

Comment: Also where is the two labels?

Comment: in each div there is 1st checkbox then one label "Task 1" then there is another which is an icon of bootstrap (delete icon).

Comment: `label` elements are meant to either have a `for` attribute that points to the `id` of the form element it is a label for, or to wrap the form element itself. See e.g. [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). If you do that, then clicking on the `label` will automatically check the checkbox.

Comment: no i dont want to check the check box by clicking on label. i want to delete the entire row by clicking on that label.

Comment: @Deepak I have added click event in the trash label. Check the answer. That should be what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$(this).closest("tr").remove()` with click event on the label having class `glyphicon` and `glyphicon-trash`:

```js
$('.glyphicon.glyphicon-trash').click(function(){
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">

  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>To Do List</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" /><label>Task 1</label><label class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" /><label>Task 2</label><label class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" /><label>Task 3</label><label class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" id="3"></label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector `input[type=label]` is not going to match any of your existing html elements. You might want to try the following selector: `$('.checkbox label.glyphicon-trash')`

Comment: And it is. The label is *inside* of the div with class `checkbox`.